# Imaginary units of complex numbers dropped by 'knitr'

Tags: r, knitr

I came across a strange issue in 'knitr' with R code containing complex numbers entered directly using the "x + yi" notation. For an illustration see the minimal example: http://goo.gl/Yj77kI

The sample code evaluates correctly, both in R console and as a code chunk when compiled with Sweave, resulting in:

```
> 1i^2
[1] -1+0i
```

However, when trying to use 'knitr' on the same document, the imaginary unit seems to get lost and what I get is:

```
1^2
## [1] 1
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Andrzej

Output of `SessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8          LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
[6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.4.7 formatR_0.9    highr_0.2.1    stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.0
```

Comment: It works for me: I get `(0+1i)^2` and `## [1] -1+0i`. Could you add the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I've added the output of `sessionInfo()` as requested.

Comment: Update: it seems to me that this might be related to the `tidy.source()` function from the 'formatR' package; when run on `1i^2` the result is `1^2`.

Comment: That is indeed a bug of the formatR package, which is really a bug of R: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-September/067523.html Before it is fixed, you will have to use the chunk option `tidy=FALSE` to disable formatR.

Comment: @Yihui -- I already tried that, and setting `tidy=FALSE` fixed the printing of the results but not the source (which still came out as `1^2`) Weird.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien the same bug is affecting the highr package, which also uses getParseData(), so `highlight=FALSE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yihui observed that this bug traces to `getParseData()`, which fails to render the `i` in its text column:

```
getParseData(parse(text="3i"))
#   line1 col1 line2 col2 id parent     token terminal text
# 1     1    1     1    2  1      2 NUM_CONST     TRUE    3
# 2     1    1     1    2  2      0      expr    FALSE
```

Both the **formatR** package (used by **knitr** to "tidy" source code) and the **highr** package (used by **knitr** to highlight code) depend on  `getParseData()`, so one had to set `highlight=FALSE, tidy=FALSE` in a code chunk to get the proper results in a `knit()`'ed document.

Following [Yihui's report](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-September/067523.html) to the R-devel mailing list, [Duncan Murdoch announced](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-September/067528.html) that `getParseData()` will be fixed in the first R-patched following the release of R-3.0.2.